# SetStandardBlobTier randomly fails to authenticate

Tags: azure, blob

Im updating blob objects from hot to cool via a Powershell script. It is randomly freezing. I just received the following exception -

> Exception calling "SetStandardBlobTier" with "1" argument(s): "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure     the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

Im pulling objects from a csv file to tier with SetStandardBlobTier cmdlet.Code below...

```
$blobsCSV.CONCATENATION | ForEach-Object {
    $blobCount.I++
    $count = $blobCount.I
    $blob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $containername -Blob $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($blob -and $blob.AccessTier -ne $tier) {
        Write-Host "($count) Setting '$_'"
        $blob.ICloudBlob.SetStandardBlobTier("$tier")
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "($count) Skipping '$_'"
    }
}
```

Any guidance will be much appreciated

Azure BLOB object update from hot to cool tier

Comment: with the reference [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-10.0.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-10.15.0) able to Set-AzStorageBlobContent [StandardBlobTier](https://i.imgur.com/JT4Il6q.png)

Comment: will give you a  How to use set-AzStorageContext

Answer (score 0):

> I have referred MSDOC for [Az.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-10.0.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-10.15.0).

```
Import-Module Az 
 $storageAccountName = "your_storage_account_name" $storageAccountKey = "your_storage_account_key" 
 $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
 $filePath = "C:\User\Downloads\hello.csv"
 
  $containerName = "sampath" $blobName = "hello.csv" 
   Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $filePath -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Force -Context $context -StandardBlobTier Cool
```

**(OR)**

```
Import-Module Az


$storageAccountName = "your_storage_account_name"
$storageAccountKey = "your_storage_account_key"


$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey


$filePath = "C:\User\Downloads\hello.csv"


$containerName = "sampath"
$blobName = "hello.csv"


$maxRetries = 3
$retryInterval = 5 # seconds

$retryCount = 0
$success = $false

while (-not $success -and $retryCount -lt $maxRetries) {
    try {
        Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $filePath -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Force -Context $context -StandardBlobTier Cool -Debug
        $success = $true
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to update blob tier: $_"
        $retryCount++
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryInterval
    }
}

if (-not $success) {
    Write-Host "Failed to update blob tier after $maxRetries retries."
}
```

**In PowerShell:**

[image]

**In Azure:**

[image]